# Room. How to store dynamic fields in the database?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

The server may return a string or an array of strings as the result of the same request. This can not be changed.
Example:
    {
      "value":"val"
    }
    {
      "value":[
        "val1",
        "val2"
         ]
    }
I know that I can write a TypeAdapter for Retrofit and then I can get this data.
But I can not understand how I save such data in the database 'Room'.

I'm trying to do the following:
I created an interface with some fields.
The field which can be String or String [] is of type Any (kotlin). Then I created 2 classes that implement this interface. In one class the type of this field is String, in another class String [].
Then I created a TypeConverter, and registered it.

Entity need to save in the database:

```
@Entity(tableName = "surveys_table")
data class Survey(
    ...
    @SerializedName("questions")
    private var questions: List<Question>
)
```

Interface that can contain a string, or an array of strings

```
interface Question {
    ...
    var value: Any
}
```

2 classes that implement this interface

```
data class QuestionWithArrayValues(
    ...,
    val _value: List<String>?

) : Question


data class QuestionWithStringValues(

    ...,
    val _value: String?

) : Question
```

Object converter

```
class QuestionsConverter{

@TypeConverter
fun fromQuestionsDbList(questions: List<Question>?): String? {
    if (questions == null) {
        return null
    }
    val gson = Gson()
    return try {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<QuestionWithStringValues>>() { }.type
        gson.toJson(questions, type)
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<QuestionWithArrayValues>>() { }.type
        gson.toJson(questions, type)
    }
}

@TypeConverter
fun toQuestionsDbList(questions: String?): List<Question>? {
    if (questions == null) {
        return null
    }
    val gson = Gson()
    return try {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<QuestionWithStringValues>>() {}.type
        gson.fromJson<List<QuestionWithStringValues>>(questions, type)
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<QuestionWithArrayValues>>() {}.type
        gson.fromJson<List<QuestionWithArrayValues>>(questions, type)
    }
}
}
```

Register converter

```
@TypeConverters(QuestionsConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() ...
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Can not figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider 
>   adding a converter for it.

I also tried using the abstract class instead of the `Question` interface. I'm not sure that you can do this at all and is there any way out of this situation ...
Does anyone know what i should do?

Comment: try adding a `?` to field in data class  `private var questions: List<Question>?`  . Uninstall app and run again

Comment: make life easy for yourself and store it as an array (convert a single string to an array of 1), regardless of what the server sends

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks! I will try it tomorrow